# Let Ansible return filename with win_find module

Tags: ansible

I'm using the [win_find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_find_module.html) with Ansible. It is returning a list, but I only want the filename returned, how would I achieve this?

I've been trying several things and thought it would work to get the filename using.

```yaml
- name: Only filename
  debug:
     msg: "{{ file_name.files.filename }}"
```

But that doesn't work.

This is the output when I run Ansible:

```yaml
ok: [test] => {
"file_name": {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 1,
    "failed": false,
    "files": [
        {
            "attributes": "Archive",
            "checksum": "9c895e101dd6497f0b561460cb45b1f219a5f2ba",
            "creationtime": 1611923974.384624,
            "exists": true,
            "extension": ".msi",
            "filename": "test1.msi",
            "hlnk_targets": [],
            "isarchive": true,
            "isdir": false,
            "ishidden": false,
            "isjunction": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreadonly": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "isshared": false,
            "lastaccesstime": 1611923974.384624,
            "lastwritetime": 1611923973.355175,
            "lnk_source": null,
            "lnk_target": null,
            "nlink": 1,
            "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
            "path": "C:\\test\\globalsync\\test1.msi",
            "sharename": null,
            "size": 18192384
        }
    ],
    "matched": 1
}
```

This is my playbook.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: get the msi name in checkMK folder
      ansible.windows.win_find:
        paths: C:\test\globalsync\
        patterns: "*.msi"
      register: file_name

    - name: return only the filename
      debug:
        msg: "{{ file_name.files.filename }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this properly, but either one of these should work:

```yaml
- name: filename
  debug:
    msg: "{{ file_name.files[0].filename }}"
```

or

```yaml
- name: filename
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.filename }}"
  loop: file_name.files
```